# ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set error even if I set a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I want to open sidekiq(bundle exec sidekiq) on my localhost, however I am getting ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set error even if I set a password on my redis.conf file.

I already set a password on my redis.conf file.
The password on redis.conf file is already on my secret.yml file like:

```rb
sidekiq_redis_url: redis://localhost:6379
sidekiq_redis_pwd: redispwd
```

Here is my sidekiq.rb

```rb
require 'sidekiq/web'
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "#{Rails.application.secrets[:sidekiq_redis_url]}", password: "#{Rails.application.secrets[:sidekiq_redis_pwd]}" }
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "#{Rails.application.secrets[:sidekiq_redis_url]}", password: "#{Rails.application.secrets[:sidekiq_redis_pwd]}" }
end
Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, false
```

Redis server version is 5.0.5 and sidekiq version is 5.2.7.
Thanks for your help.